# Lightning Layout scrollable is breaking the table and showing only few columns

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-recordeditform, scrolling

I am working on the Custom product family selection LWC component, I added the rows and columns in the lightning layout using table. For 4 fields the table is showing all the rows and columns, but if the fields are increased the styling is not looking good and the first few columns are not displayed. I have around 20 fields to show as columns. Can anyone suggest how to show all the fields without breaking anything?
In the below screenshot Product Family name is not displayed even though added on the component.

**LWC:**

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isShowModal}>

        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
            aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- modal header start -->


                <!-- modal body start -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">

                    <template>
                        <div class="slds-scrollable">
                            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">
                                <tr>

                                    <lightning-layout horizontal-align="space">
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Product Family</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Segment</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Description</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Price</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Units</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Years</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Total</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Test2</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                            <div class="textCenter">Test 3</div>
                                        </lightning-layout-item>

                                    </lightning-layout>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    
                                            <lightning-layout horizontal-align="space">
                                                <lightning-layout-item data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} size="2"
                                                    padding="around-small"> 'Test Name' </lightning-layout-item>

                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="text" data-id={selectedRecObj.Id}
                                                            variant="label-hidden" field-name="Segment__c"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>

                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="text" variant="label-hidden"
                                                            data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} field-name="Description"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>

                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="number" variant="label-hidden"
                                                            data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} field-name="UnitPrice"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>

                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="number" variant="label-hidden"
                                                            data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} field-name="Units__c"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>
                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="number" variant="label-hidden"
                                                            data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} field-name="Total__c"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>
                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="number" variant="label-hidden"
                                                            data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} field-name="Test2__c"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>
                                                <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning-input-field type="number" variant="label-hidden"
                                                            data-id={selectedRecObj.Id} field-name="Test3__c"
                                                            onchange={oppProductChange}></lightning-input-field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </lightning-layout-item>

                                            </lightning-layout>
                                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                    <!--<div class="slds-scrollable modal-container slds-modal__container">-->
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
        
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: You should use an [`slds-grid`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/), not a table, where possible. There are many advantages, including flow handling and responsive design.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks I used slds-grid and slds-col it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to address tabular layouts using the [`slds-grid`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) rather than looking to use tables.

The main benefit of `slds-grid` is that it handles flow and responsive design for you. The main limitation is that it can only address up to 12 columns.

If you have 12 or fewer column requirements, it would be best to switch.